# x86-64 recursive multiply function

Tags: x86-64, multiplication

I'm trying to make a function in x86-64 assembly that multiplies two numbers x and y and returns the output without using a loop or the mul operator. This is the code that I've came up with but I don't know why it always just returns y. Any help is appreciated. x in edi, y in esi.

```
mul:
    xorl %eax, %eax
    testl %edi, %edi  #if x == 0 return 0 //base case 1
    je done1
    testl %esi, %esi  #if y == 0 return 0 //base case 1
    je done1

    cmpl $1, %edi   #if x == 1, return y //base case 2
    je done2

    addl %esi, %eax   #add eax by y (esi) x (edi) times
    decl %edi       #decrease x by 1 each run of the function. B stays the same
    call mul

done1:
    ret

done2:              #if x == 1, return y
    movl %esi, %eax
    ret
```

Comment: You could fully unroll the shift and add method; that needs at most 32 "iterations" so it's possible to make it totally branchless, and satisfy the requirement of no loop and no mul.  (But defeat the purpose of learning to debug your recursive code.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It always returns "y", because you decrement `%edi` with

```
decl %edi
```

until it reaches the value "1". Then the following instruction sequence is executed:

```
call mul          # CALL -->
...
xorl %eax, %eax   # RESET accumulator value to 0
testl %edi, %edi  
je done1          # NOT TAKEN
testl %esi, %esi  
je done1          # NOT TAKEN
cmpl $1, %edi     # if x == 1, return y //base case 2
je done2          # HERE - THIS JUMP IS TAKEN
...
movl %esi, %eax   # MOVE y to return register %eax
ret               # It always returns y in %eax
```

---

To fix this situtation, first move the line `xorl %eax, %eax` before the `mul` label. Then remove the line `movl %esi, %eax` to preserve the `%eax` value as return value.

So this could be a solution:

```
    xorl %eax, %eax   # Set result value to "0"
    # check for 0 for "y" input 
    testl %esi, %esi  # if y == 0 return 0 //base case 1
    je done1          # immediately return on zero
mul:    
    test %edi, %edi   # if x == 0, exit recursive calls
    je done1
    addl %esi, %eax   # add y (esi) to eax 
    decl %edi         # decrease x by 1 each run of the function. B stays the same
    call mul
    # PASS-THROUGH on stack unwinding
done1:
    ret
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested it, but you should get the idea.